# Why does Rails 5 order test cases randomly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, ruby-on-rails-5

It's mentioned in the upgrade guide [Rails 5 will order tests randomly](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html). It's trivial to revert to fixed order, but I'm just wondering why this change was made? Is it to support parallel testing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Random test ordering is good practice. If you always do your test in a fixed order there is a chance your tests depend on each other. Each test should have no side effects, and random ordering guarantees this.

Comment: I guess that's it but I feel like a better approach would be to periodically run a whole battery of entire suites in various random orders. And then for regular regression tests to test a code change, continue testing in a deterministic order so that I don't have to worry about whether it was the code change that caused the test to suddenly break, or the order change. At least I'd want the ability to go back and run the same test order as the previous successful run.

Comment: If the Rails 5 implementation works like most things, there should be a seed for the random order printed when you run the tests. There should be a way to specify for the tests to use that seed on a rerun (use the same "random" order). I haven't used Rails 5 at all, so I can't tell you **how** to do that, of course.

Comment: Me neither. Hopefully it works as you describe, with the seed logged.

Comment: At no point has random test ordering become a good practice. This is a ridiculous rails-ism that was born out of people writing bad tests that were dependent on ordering. Running them in random order is a ridiculous counter-productive solution that results in arbitrary ordering of test failures in the output.

Comment: --seed allows you to repeat tests in a specific order. If you really want to  put load on your CI, let it iterate about some fixed seeds :-)

Answer (score 2):

Refereed to [Rails 5 Awesome features](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/rails-5-awesome-features-changes-sumit-munot-ruby-on-rails-?trk=pulse_spock-articles)

Rails 5 order test cases randomly, the new runner is, in fact, my favourite piece of Rails 5. I love minitest, and I always was a bit envy of RSpec users, as they have a great runner that allows you to specify the file and line number of a failing spec.

Now, thanks to Yves Senn, we have the same feature when using Rails’ minitest.